# How to pass data from back-end to front-end in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a node project that uses PUG/Jade files to render the webpages. Once every minute a JS file is executed that updates a redis database, and I want the GUI to also update once a minute so as to reflect any changes.

Below is a simplified version of how the data is currently passed across:

1. User accesses url `.../home`
2. `routes.js` executes `router.get('/home', controller.renderHome)`
3. `controller.js` executes the following:

   ```
   function getData(){
        return { some_data } 
   }

   renderHome: async (req, res) => {
       res.render('home', getDetails())
   }
   ```

I can then access the data in the .pug file.

Using this method I only get the updated data when the route is accessed (i.e. the page is refreshed). But the data is used to draw graphs which I want to update every minute.

How should I instead go about passing the data through to the GUI that would allow me to simply re-draw the graphs every minute as opposed to forcing a browser reload each time (something I'm guessing is bad practice)

Comment: Look for "Ajax". Depending on which libraries you are using client-side (If any), how you implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)
2. Expose an API that your client-side JavaScript can poll at a specified interval for updates.

WebSocket is probably the way to go: https://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

use Socket.io https://socket.io/ then use a  `setInterval` function in your front end to emit a socket.io event to the backend every minute`